Distribution of passengers into distinct cars
In four cars, 16 passengers randomly enter. What is the probability of the following events:
a) 4 passengers enter the first car
b) each car receives exactly 4 passengers
I am trying to decide between $\frac{3^{12} \binom{16}{4}}{4^{16}}$
and $\frac{\binom{15}{12}}{\binom{19}{16}}$ for a).
In essence, why does it yield different answers if we consider people indistinguishable.

[1] People are considered to be distinguishable unless expressly told otherwise. [2] Distribution using stars and bars is not equiprobable, so unsuitable where probabilities are asked for.

@trueblueanil Why is it not equiprobable? Thank you.

Part $a)$ is poorly phrased.  It's not clear whether you mean exactly $4$ people or at least $4$ people.

You can easily understand that having all the passengers  (or 12 passengers, if one car is reserved for exactly 4) in one car is far more unlikely than a more even distribution.

@trueblueanil Thank you!


In essence, why does it yield different answers if we consider people indistinguishable.

Let's illustrate this with a simpler problem. There are two cars. Eight passengers get in the cars. If you view the passengers as distinguishable, there are 64 different possible arrangements of passengers (each passenger chooses car 0 or car 1 independently). If you view the passengers as indistinguishable, there are only 9 possible arrangements (car 0 has 0, 1, 2, ... or 9 passengers, while car 1 has the rest).
In the setting of probability, we would like to know in which of these situations, if either, are all the arrangements equally likely? The answer depends on how the passengers choose which car to enter.
If each person flips a coin to decide which car to enter, then there are 64 equally probable outcomes of the coin flips. Each of these leads to exactly one unique outcome among the 64 arrangements of distinguished passengers. So those are all equally probable. However, this is not true for the arrangements of indistinguished passengers. For example, 8 of the coin flip outcomes lead to 1 passenger in car 0, while only 1 of them leads to 0 passengers in car 0. So the arrangements of indistinguished passengers are not equally likely.
The result can be different if the passengers use a different method to choose their cars. For example, perhaps they get together and decide how many people will get in car 0, choosing 0, 1, 2, ... 9 with equal probability. Then they select a random subset of that size to get into car 0, while the rest get into car 1. In this case, the indistinguished arrangements are equally likely, while the distinguished arrangements are not equally likely.
It is also possible for neither set of arrangements to be equiprobable. For example, the people could get together, pick a car randomly, and all get into that one, leaving the other one empty. Then neither the distinguished nor the indistinguished arrangements are equiprobable. Indeed, most of them have probability 0.
In this problem, all you are  told is:

In four cars, 16 passengers randomly enter.

In a sense, this is not enough information to solve the problem, because you are not explicitly told how it is determined which passengers enter which cars.
The "standard" interpretation  of the sentence is that each of the 16 passengers makes an independent, uniformly random choice between the cars. You could reasonably argue that this interpretation is not possible to derive from the text of the problem. And in that case, you have to stop, because there is not enough information to solve the problem.
However if you do adopt this interpretation, as in the simpler version of the problem, it means that the distinguished arrangements are equiprobable, while the indistinguished ones are not.

Thanks!  I get it.

For (a), if you mean exactly $4$ passengers enter the first car, than this is $Bin(16,1/4)$ distribution and the answer is
$$
\binom{16}{4}\left(\frac14\right)^4 \left(1-\frac14\right)^{16-4}.
$$
For (b), it's  multinomial distribution  with $n=16$, $k=4$ and $p_1=p_2=p_3=p_4=\frac14$.

My book says that for b) it is 16C412C48C4*4C4/4^16

To count the numerator, you can use any of the equivalent forms of the multinomial coefficient, viz $$\binom{16}{4,4,4,4} \equiv \binom{16}{4}\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom44 \equiv \frac{16!}{414!4!4!}$$

Indeed, multinomial distribution gives $\binom{16}{4,4,4,4}\left(\frac14\right)^{16}$.
